# Other expressions for "to overcome obstacles"

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for a more original way to say "to overcome obstacles," preferably something figurative. The [synonyms](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-synonyms/to%20overcome%20obstacles) I found don't quite cut it.

> Partisan politics are at the heart of these problems and should be the first obstacle to overcome in fixing our democracies.

Comment: Please explain why they don't quite cut it -- otherwise you will inevitably get more suggestions that don't fit.  A good method is to provide a sample sentence that has a gap where the expression would go. That way we have something to work with.

Comment: If the obstacles are personal or internal you might go with "to face/beat/overcome one's demons"

Comment: I'm looking for an image, a metaphor. The context is to overcome political obstacles.

Comment: "steep hill to climb", "first hurdle to cross", "the first step in a thousand-mile march", are all metaphors for tackling a large issue or problem.

Comment: @KristinaLopez post them as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three relatively common metaphors for overcoming obstacles using OP's example sentence:

> - "Partisan politics are at the heart of these problems and should be the ***first hurdle to cross*** in fixing our democracies."
> - Partisan politics are at the heart of these problems and will be a ***steep hill to climb*** in fixing our democracies.
> - Partisan politics are at the heart of these problems and should be the ***first step in a thousand-mile march*** toward fixing our democracies.